# SQLite sorting a column containing numbers or text

Tags: sqlite

I have a column containing user entry descriptions, these descriptions can be anything however i do need them sorted into a logical order.

The text can be anything like 
16 to 26 months
40 to 60 months 
Literacy
Mathematics

When i order these in sql statement the text items return fine. However any beginning with numbers come back in an order not logical

i.e.

16 to 26 months 
will be before 
8 to 20 months

i understand why as it takes first character etc but don't know how to alter sql statement (using sqlite) to improve the performance without messing up the entries beginning with text

When i cast to numeric the numbers are fine the items beginning with text go wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is sorting the values in "natural order". To achieve this you will need to implement your own [collating sequence](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation); SQLite doesn't provide one for this case.

There are some questions (and answers) regarding this topic here on SO, but they are for other RDBMS. The best I could find in a quick search was this:

http://wiki.ozanh.com/doku.php?id=python:database:sqlite:how_to_natural_sort

You should think about improving your table schema, e. g. splitting the period into separate integer columns (monthsMin, monthsMax) instead of using text, which would make sorting much easier. You can always build a string from this values if necessary.